# Codename one - BluetoothLE MATCH_MODE_STICKY vs. MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, codenameone

What's the difference between MATCH_MODE_STICKY and MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE in CN1 library for BLE? This is the *matchMode* argument in in the startScan method.

```
startScan(ActionListener callback, ArrayList services, boolean allowDuplicates, int scanMode, int matchMode, int matchNum, int callbackType)
```

I can't find any documentation that explains what's the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the Android's [Bluetooth LE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html) documentation:

> MATCH_MODE_STICKY: For sticky mode, higher threshold of signal
>   strength and sightings is required before reporting by hw
>
> MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE: In Aggressive mode, hw will determine a match
>   sooner even with feeble signal strength and few number of
>   sightings/match in a duration.

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked in Android doc. first :)